# Compiler differences with use of templated overloads

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-c++, operator-overloading

I have a pretty specific situation where I'm feeding a bunch of data to a hasher-like class. In particular, one data type that I use has a member whose type depends on the supertype's type parameter. Long story short, here's a piece of code that illustrates this behaviour :

```cpp
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

// Some dummy priority structs to select overloads
struct priority0 { };
struct priority1 : priority0 { };

// This is the hasher-like function
struct Catcher
{
    // Ideally we feed everything to this object through here
    template <typename T> Catcher& operator<<(const T& v)
    {
        add(v, priority1{}); // always attempt to call the highest-priority overload
        return *this;
    }
    
    // For floating-point data types
    template <typename T> auto add(const T& v, priority1) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, void>
    {
        std::cout << "caught float/double : " << v << std::endl;
    }
    
    // For ranges
    template <class T> auto add(const T& range, priority1) -> decltype(begin(range), end(range), void())
    {
        for(auto const& v : range)
            *this << v;
    }
    
    // For chars
    void add(char c, priority1)
    {
        std::cout << c;
        std::cout.flush();
    }
    
    // When everything else fails ; ideally should never happen
    template <typename T> void add(const T& v, priority0)
    {
        assert(false && "should never happen");
    }
};

// The one data type. Notice how the primary template and the
// specialization have a `range` member of different types
template <class T> struct ValueOrRange
{
    struct Range
    {
        T min;
        T max;
    };
    Range range;
    T value;
};

template <> struct ValueOrRange<std::string>
{
    std::vector<std::string> range;
    std::string value;
};

// Overload operator<< for Catcher outside of the
// class to allow for processing of the new data type

// Also overload that for `ValueOrRange<T>::Range`. SFINAE should make sure
// that this behaves correctly (?)
template <class T> Catcher& operator<<(Catcher& c, const typename ValueOrRange<T>::Range& r)
{
    return c << r.min << r.max;
}

template <class T> Catcher& operator<<(Catcher& c, const ValueOrRange<T>& v)
{
    return c << v.range << v.value;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ValueOrRange<std::string> vor1{{}, "bleh"};
    ValueOrRange<float> vor2{{0.f, 1.f}, 0.5f};
    
    Catcher c;
    c << vor1; // works fine, displays "bleh"
    c << vor2; // fails the assert in Catcher::add(const T&, priority0) with T = ValueOrRange<float>::Range
    return 0;
}
```

While the line `c << vor1` gets resolved correctly through the various overloads and has the intended effect, the second line `c << vor2` fails the assert.

- What I want to happen : `c << vor2` calls `Catcher& operator<<(Catcher& s, const ValueOrRange<float>& v)`, which in turn calls `Catcher& operator<<(Catcher& s, const typename ValueOrRange<float>::Range& r)`
- What does happen : instead of `Catcher& operator<<(Catcher& s, const typename ValueOrRange<float>::Range& r)`, it is `Catcher& Catcher::operator<<(const T& v)` with `T = typename ValueOrRange<float>::Range` that is called, and thus the assert fails.

Worthy of note is that this same code has the intended effect on MSVC, and fails the assert on GCC.

Any idea on how I should fix that ?

Comment: In `template <class T> auto operator<<(Catcher& c, const typename ValueOrRange<T>::Range& r)`, `T` is [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts). This overload could only ever be called with explicitly specified template arguments, e.g. `operator<< <float> (c, v.range)`; `T` cannot be automatically deduced from the arguments. This is why `c << v.range` falls through to the catch-all overload.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I see. In the specific case of strings though, the range argument is just a vector and is expected to be processed through the range-based overload, so I guess the distinction has to be made within the function itself. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to feedback from Igor Tandetnik, I got rid of the `::Range`-specific overload and simply went for checking `std::is_same_v<T, std::string>`. A little less modular than I'd like, but it'll do the trick.

```cpp
// A single function will do the trick
template <class T> Catcher& operator<<(Catcher& c, const ValueOrRange<T>& v)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
        c << v.range;
    else
        c << v.range.min << v.range.max;
    return c << v.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Catcher& operator<<(Catcher& c, const typename ValueOrRange<T>::Range& r)`, `T` in non deducible.

One work around would be `friend` function:

```cpp
template <class T> struct ValueOrRange
{
    struct Range
    {
        T min;
        T max;
        
        friend Catcher& operator<<(Catcher& c, const Range& r)
        {
            return c << r.min << r.max;
        }        
    };
    Range range;
    T value;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a15576615276686)